# YFinance stocks not appearing

Tags: python, yfinance

I am using yfinance in Python to get a list of stocks from different dates, but I noticed the stock BRKB keeps appearing as None. Previously, I thought it was my code that was the problem but when I tried it in a shell, the same error occured. Does anyone know whether this is intentional, or if I am doing something wrong? [image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ticker symbol for Berkshire's B stocks is denoted with `BRK-B` not `BRKB`, as seen [on the yahoo website](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BRK-B/).

```
import yfinance as yf

print(yf.Ticker("BRKB").info)
print(yf.Ticker("BRK-B").info)
```

**Output:**

```
{'regularMarketPrice': None, 'preMarketPrice': None, 'logo_url': ''}
{'zip': '68131', 'sector': 'Financial Services', 'fullTimeEmployees': 372000, 'longBusinessSummary': ...}
```